# Call to a member function fetch_field() on a non-object MySQLiDB

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-mysqlidb

Hi i cant use INSERT UPDATE function with this class: [MySQLiDB](https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class).
Im trying write data to mysql and if exists this data then need update. So i use `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE...`. My code like this:

```
$db->rawQuery("INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field2=VALUES(field2),field3=VALUES(field3)", array("value1",value2,value2));
```

this code works fine. But when use this code in cycle and give values by another array shows me this error: `Call to a member function fetch_field() on a non-object in...`. This is code in cycle:

```
$db->rawQuery("INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field2=VALUES(field2),field3=VALUES(field3)", array($value[$i][value1],$value[$i][value2],$value[$i][value3]));
```

What i can do in this situation?

Comment: -1 for providing not an error message but only stub. How we are supposed to know the code that leads to the error?

Comment: im sorry but its Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_field() on a non-object in... Really fatal error

Comment: still only a stub. Why do you continuously omit the vital part?

Comment: https://github.com/ajillion/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class this is source of class

Comment: The vital part of the **error message**. Why not to post it whole, not cutting out the **file name** and the **line number**?

Comment: Okay Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_field() on a non-object in /project/classes/mysqlidb.class.php on line 427

Comment: Oh, you're so kind. Thank you, mister. Thank you very much

Comment: so what you can offer to solve this problem.

Comment: Read the answer below

Comment: Thank you for answer. But my codes wrote in MySQLiDB class it takes more time to change. I cant change all codes.

Comment: Well, if you want to stick to that faulty library, you have to debug its faulty code, find the error and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use MySQLiDB. It is unusable in many ways.

You can use [safemysql](https://github.com/colshrapnel/safemysql) instead:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2,field3) VALUES (?s,?s,?s) 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field2=VALUES(field2),field3=VALUES(field3)";
$db->query($sql, $value[$i]['value1'],$value[$i]['value2'],$value[$i]['value3']);
```

Or, in a much simpler way:

```
foreach ($value as $row)
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO table1 SET ?u
            ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field2=VALUES(field2),field3=VALUES(field3)";
    $db->query($sql, $row);
}
```

(only if `$value` coming from the trusted source though)

You could also create a query for the single insert

```
$ins = array();
foreach ($value as $row) {
    $ins[] = $db->parse("(?s,?s,?s)",$row['value1'],$row['value2'],$row['value3']);
}
$instr = implode(",",$ins);
$sql = "INSERT INTO table1 (field1,field2,field3) VALUES ?p 
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field2=VALUES(field2),field3=VALUES(field3)";
$db->query($sql, $ins);
```